# Accessing data inside a render function of a functional vuejs component

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use a functional component to render multiple elements without having to have a single root element but I can't seem to have access to the component `data`, see this simplified example:

Trying to access `context.data` logs an empty object `{}`:

```html
<div id="app">
  <hello />
</div>
```

```
Vue.component('hello', {
  functional: true,
  render: function(h, context) {
    console.log(context.data) // This logs {}

    return new Array(5).fill(1).map((_, index) => h('p', {}, 'Hello world'))
  },
  data () {
    return {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: '<p>foo</p>',
      bar: 'bar'
    }
  }
})
```

[A working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u97fbx50/6/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional component has no data which is why it does not receive `data` in the context. You can find additional information in [this section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) of the manual

If you want to render a component without having to use a single root element you might want to give [vue-fragment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragments) a try.

Comment: Thanks ! That makes sense. I actually tried `vue-fragment` before trying to use functional components and render functions, but I kept running into errors when I was trying to render multiple component that use `vue-fragment` as root element (Errors that might be related to https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment/issues/18). Anyway, I got around my initial problem by wrapping my multiple `tr` inside `tbody` elements since it seems like it's possible to render multiple `tbody` inside a `table`